# Quiero saber cuál es el IP Address que está utilizando mysql

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu

He usado homestead/laravel y sé que el IP address de mi base de datos puede ser 192.168.20.20 ó 192.168.10.10, pero quiero saber cómo es con ruby on rails con otro entorno diferente no se cuál es el puerto ya he colocado localhost. Realmente cómo puedo saber cuál es el puerto para conectar mi vagrant+rails con la base de datos, estoy utilizando windows.

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero si queres saber la dirección ip del servidor de mysql, puedes usar una consulta como la siguiente:
SHOW VARIABLES
WHERE Variable_name IN (
'hostname',
'port')

Comment: @Mariano yo entiendo claramente que el OP necesita averiguar tanto el IP como el puerto de su base de datos MySQL

Comment: @Mariano basta con decir que se puede realizar un `ping` al server y posiblemente un `telnet` mediante el hostname. Si no se posee este dato, entonces no hay manera de obtener dicha información. Si requiere más ayuda, que brinde más información sobre el problema real que afronta.

Comment: Luego de la edición, la pregunta es menos clara aún. Por favor intenta aportar los datos **reales** de tu entorno y brindar un poco de contexto para facilitar la tarea de alguien que quiera ayudarte. Ahora mencionas "*Por ejemplo he usado*", y en un comentario a una respuesta "*ubuntu/xenial64*". También decís "*en un entorno diferente*"... ¡¿en cuál?! Esta pregunta es cada vez más confusa.

Comment: He usado gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development he seguido este tutorial. Yo tengo windows pero uso vagrant con virtual box para rails, lo que quiero es conectar navicat con mi entorno.

Comment: Si te fijas en los comentarios del post de abajo muestro en toda mi configuraciones.

Answer (score 4):

Para revisar el puerto en el cual está corriendo mysql, debes revisar en el archivo `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` la línea que contenga `port = 12345`.
En caso que no esté la línea, mysql corre por defecto en el puerto 3306.
Ahora, por el lado de rails, la definición de la conexión a la base de datos se encuentra en tu proyecto, en `config/database.yml`, ahí fíjate en los campos:

```
host: localhost
port: 3306
```

Si no encontraste nada fuera de lo normal, agrega a tu pregunta los errores que te está arrojando rails al ejecutar la aplicación, para hacerse una mejor idea de que está pasando. Solo para confirmar, tanto mysql como rails están corriendo en la misma máquina homestead, ¿cierto?.

Recomendación aparte. A pesar de que Homestead viene con mysql, nginx o redis, que son herramientas que vas a usar con rails, en general esa vagrant box viene configurada principalmente para trabajar con Laravel. Te recomendaría que usases otro box, como los de [Rove.io](http://rove.io/?pattern=rails), [railsbox.io](https://railsbox.io/) o algún otro box que googlees que esté preparado para funcionar con rails. Mejor aún si estás aprendiendo rails, que configures la máquina por tu cuenta. Te demorarás más, pero aprenderás de qué cosas necesitas para funcionar en una máquina rails y como van conectadas las piezas entre si.

**Actualización**

Para acceder a un puerto específico de tu máquina virtual desde la máquina padre, puedes hacer redireccionamiento de puertos configurando tu `Vagrantfile` de la siguiente forma:

```
# dentro de tu bloque de `Vagrant.configure`
config.vm.network "forwarded_port", guest: 3306, host: 3307
```

donde `guest` es el puerto de la máquina virtual al cual quieres acceder y `host` será un puerto disponible de tu máquina padre el cual redireccionará las peticiones a la máquina virtual.
Para el ejemplo mostrado, si en tu máguina padre accedes a `127.0.0.1:3307` podrás acceder a la instancia de mysql corriendo en tu máquina virtual.

Ahora, si esto no te es suficiente, puedes crear una red privada para acceder a tu máquina virtual, ya sea usando DHCP para que le sea asignada una ip dinámicamente:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", type: "dhcp"
```

o especificando una ip estática:

```
config.vm.network "private_network", ip: "192.168.50.4"
```

Comment: si, pero el que instale fue este https://gorails.com/guides/using-vagrant-for-rails-development

Comment: @eduardo2207 pero en esa guía usan `ubuntu/xenial64`, no `laravel/homestead`. No entiendo por que mencionaste el segundo en tu pregunta

Comment: si lo mencione a manera de ejemplo, pero como puedo conectarme? cuál sería el IP Address?

Comment: @eduardo2207 revisa la actualización de mi respuesta

Comment: disculpa pero lo tengo configurado así mi vagrantfile https://jsfiddle.net/4k13Lvxv/1/

Comment: 1130 - host'192.168.50.1' is not allowed to connect to this mysql server

Comment: @eduardo2207 por favor pon información más relevante, que pongas el error no sirve de mucho si no dices que hiciste para generarlo. Lo de jsfiddle (que aparte un vagrantfile no tiene mucho que ver con html) también es información que puedes agregar a tu pregunta, no es necesario ponerlo en otra plataforma si ya estás usando S.O. ¿Has logrado hacer ping a 192.168.50.4?

Comment: @eduardo2207 a todo esto, cuando puse los ejemplos de `config.vm.network` me refería a que los agregaras a tu `Vagrant.configure` ya existente, no que copiaras/pegaras tal cual lo puse yo, la ip también la puedes cambiar si deseas.

Answer (score 1):

debe haber un archivo q contiene la configuracion, puede ser un properties o un archivo my.conf buscalo en tu directorio por default el puerto es el 3306 en mysql, si han cambiado la configuracion seguro fue en el my.conf, por default mysql toma la ip de la maquina donde esta instalado, checalo y mee dices como te va

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ktj6f3wj/1/ he revisado y es 3306 también le he colocado contraseña a mi usuario en mysql -u root -p  secret, y he podido entrar sólo que con navicat no!

Comment: Si ya pudiste accesar en Mysql, solo sebes configurar correctamente Navicat, no seberia ser muyt dificil, si compartes una panatalla de los parametros de conexión, eso sería util para ayudarte a determinar que estas haciendo mal.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/r1okvyt7/1/ está es la información de la conexión. También busco

Comment: Ok, veo que estas utilizando vagrant, no he realizado una configuración con esta herramienta, pero la siguiente linea me causa ruido:

mysql: {
        server_root_password: ''
      }

Ahí deberías escribir secret, ya que tu usuario root tiene esa clave.

Es lo único que pude observar en tu archivo.

Answer (score 0):

Esto ha funcionado para mi:

```
mysql
show global variables like 'PORT';
```

tomado de:
[1]: https://www.enmimaquinafunciona.com/pregunta/8016/como-comprobar-en-que-puerto-se-ejecuta-mysql